# Only use part of screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My screen is broken, but perfectly straight along one side and the rest (majority) of the screen is perfectly fine.  I would like to adjust my display so that my computer thinks that the display ends where the screen is broken.  Are there any utilities, command line or otherwise that would help me here?  I have a 15-inch 3360 x 2100 retina display with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB graphics card.  The computer is Early 2013.

Answer (score 4):

[SwitchRes X](http://www.madrau.com) might be able to help you, it can modify screen settings that are usually inaccessible.

There is a [custom resolutions](http://www.madrau.com/srx_howtouseit/srx_howtouseit/srx_timings.html) section

[image: custom resolution settings]

Comment: WARNING: this program changes the settings in a very dirty way and its very hard to restore to the default settings afterwards!