# Display on only a part of the external screen on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, resolution

Is there a way or an application on macOS that would allow me to display on only a part of the screen and fill the rest of the screen with black bars?

I am using an LG 55inch OLED 4K TV as an external monitor.
On Windows, I used to set a lower resolution and use center scaling in order to prevent the display to be stretched to fit the screen. So I end up with black bars filling the rest of the TV screen.

I hope I can do the same on Mac.

I would like to add that over/under-scan settings don't show up to me on Monterey OS.
Also I tried to use SwitchResX but it doesn't support anymore resolution full customization on Apple silicon, so most of the settings are grayed out.

Comment: Have you tried the [over/underscan settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202763)? Have you seen this related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/142948/24324 ?

Comment: Unfortunately over/under-scan settings don't show up to me on Monterey OS.
Regarding the related question; SwitchResX doesn't support resolution full customization on Apple silicon, so most of the settings are grayed out.

Comment: Well, these are good points to [edit] into your question, otherwise people might keep suggesting things you've tried already and didn't work.